# How do i grab certain parts of an inputted string?

Tags: python, jython

Mainly, i'm trying to just have a user input some data

```
def getmonsterData():
  monster1 = raw_input("Enter the Monster Affinity|HP|AD> ")
  x = monster1.index('|');
  affinityType = monster1[0:x]
  printNow(affinitytype)
```

i was able to make a variable to store the Monster Affinity so when printed it lists what the user entered(ie: fire/earth) but i'm not sure how to grab and create a similar one for HP and AD

this will print whatever I listed Monster1's Affinity to such as Fire. This works all good and well,
but when I'm not too sure how to splice strings using Jython/Python.. maybe something like

```
HP = monster1[affinityType+1:x] ? not too sure how to do this
```

similarly I need to get the last variable AD, which i believe i can do if i get HP variable

```
 y = len(monster1)
 AD = monster1[x+1:y]
```

any input on this would be helpful :) thanks

Comment: What would you expected input look like?

Answer (score 4):

You can use split:

```
>>> aff,HP,AD = raw_input("Enter the Monster Affinity|HP|AD> ").split('|')
Enter the Monster Affinity|HP|AD> a|11|22
>>> aff
'a'
>>> HP
'11'
>>> AD
'22'
```

But if you want to use index, you can use the start argument (`S.index(sub [,start [,end]]) -> int`)

```
>>> monster =  raw_input("Enter the Monster Affinity|HP|AD> ")
Enter the Monster Affinity|HP|AD> a|11|22
>>> x = monster.index('|')
>>> monster[:x]
'a'
>>> y = monster.index('|',x+1)
>>> monster[x+1:y]
'11'
>>> monster[y+1:]
'22'
```

Comment: This is the correct answer, and OP should be careful that if someone doesn't include the 2 `|` in their input then an error will be thrown.